# Knockoutjs - Set CSS class based on value in array

Tags: css, knockout.js

here is the html table I am working on:

```
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: xusers.list">
      <tr data-bind="css:{'approved-false' : member()==1 }">
        <td data-bind="text: member"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: expired"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: email"></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
```

The value of the array item member displays in the table just fine but my css call is not working no matter what syntax I have tried.  I just want to apply this class if member is true (member contains either 1 or 0).

What am I missing?

Additional Code - Am I overwriting observable?...Here is the only place anything is written to the array.

```
if (!data) {
   ...
} 
else {
    if (data.length) {
        var curItem;
        for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
            curItem = new xuser();
            curItem.name = data[i].name;
            curItem.email = data[i].email;
            curItem.city = data[i].city;
            curItem.region = data[i].region;
            curItem.country = data[i].country;
            curItem.expires = data[i].expires;
            curItem.member = data[i].member;
            curItem.expired = data[i].expired;
            xusers.list.push(curItem)
            totalRecs = data[i].TotalCount;
        }
    }
} // if (!data)/else
```

Comment: the css class name is `approved-false` ?

Comment: Shouldn't this look like so `"css: { approved-false: member() == 0 }"` ?

Comment: yes...I posted an incorrect syntax...but it is throwing a member() TypeError (not a function) anyway....but thanks for answering!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, just had it backward: see http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: xusers.list">
  <tr data-bind="css:{'approved-false': member() == 1 }">
    <td data-bind="text: member"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: expired"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: email"></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

You are also overwriting your observables, see below (this assumes that all fields on `curItem` are observables, update your own as needed):

```
if (!data) {
   ...
} 
else {
    if (data.length) {
        var curItem;
        for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
            curItem = new xuser();
            curItem.name(data[i].name);
            curItem.email(data[i].email);
            curItem.city(data[i].city);
            curItem.region(data[i].region);
            curItem.country(data[i].country);
            curItem.expires(data[i].expires);
            curItem.member(data[i].member);
            curItem.expired(data[i].expired);
            xusers.list.push(curItem)

            // this should probably be somewhere else
            totalRecs = data[i].TotalCount; 
        }
    }
} // if (!data)/else
```

Comment: I tried that as well...(guess I just posted one of the MANY things I have tried) but when I put that in, I get nothing returned (breaks my whole foreach...no results are returned.)

Comment: @RoyBarrow what kind of error are you seeing in the console?

Comment: Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: TypeError: member is not a function;
Bindings value: css:{'approved-false': member()==1}

Comment: is `member` an observable? is it on the object in the loop, or a member of `xusers`? if it's not observable, just remove the parens

Comment: You can see from the 2nd TD listed (text: member) that it is member of xusers and is marked as follows in the xuser model:

          _self.url           = ko.observable("");
   _self.member        = ko.observable("");
   _self.expired       = ko.observable("");

Comment: Thank you for your quick answers!!  Much appreciated!

Comment: it seems that you must be overwriting the observable somewhere instead of setting it (think model = "new value" instead of model("new value")). do you have any more code you can show?

Comment: @RoyBarrow put the code in your question, not in my answer; people may not see it down here (and it looks like you're overwriting the observable)

Comment: @RoyBarrow updated my answer to show the proper setting of the fields, assuming they're all observables

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH....as you can tell I am new to KO...I now understand a lot more thanks to you!

Comment: I would recommend checking out the knockout documentation, there are some really good examples, and you may even find things you didn't know you needed